# Inserting data into tables - MS SQL and Node JS

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm using rest-mssql-nodejs to connect to MS SQL through node. They are both on a Ubuntu VPS

This is the structure of the table (Someone else made it)

[image: table structure]

When I run something like "select *", or select an user with an specific id or even update data like this:

```
const insertResult = await rest.executeQuery('update [User] set LastName = @lastname where UserID = @id', [{
        name:'id',
        type:'int',
        value:7
    },{
        name:'lastname',
        type:'varchar',
        value:'test2'
    }]);
```

...it works but trying to insert a new user like this:

```
await rest.executeQuery("INSERT INTO [User] (UserID, FirstName) values (@id, @name)", [{
        name:'id',
        type:'int',
        value:8
    },{
        name:'name',
        type:'nvarchar',
        value:'David'
    }]);
```

...does not insert a new user to my table.
How can I make my INSERT?
Do I have to match the structure of the table by inserting into mandatory columns or what?

Comment: What do you mean by: "does not work." ?

Comment: My INSERT query does not insert a new row, it returns a NULL to the server and when I look up all of the rows inside my table, no new user has been inserted.

Comment: Can you share the actual `create table` script [instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Have you considered what would happen if the UserID was an `identity?` Also just FYI, defining all the varchar columns as `(max)` is very bad practice, columns should be sized according to the data they will contain. will someone's name be more than 50 characters? A phone number more than 20?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have access to that at the moment .

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had to fill out every row that was "not null" except for UserID and UserGuid since they self generate. This is my new code:

```
const insertResult = await rest.executeQuery("INSERT INTO [User] (PasswordRequiresReset, DateCreated, DateUpdated, Active) values (@requireReset, @created, @updated, @active)", [{
        name:'id',
        type:'int',
        value:8
    },{
        name:'guid',
        type:'nvarchar',
        value:'01DD7D07-CA98-4BBD-ABA6-D71B75A59BXX'
    },{
        name:'requireReset',
        type:'bit',
        value: false
    },{
        name:'created',
        type:'datetime',
        value: '2021-03-27T23:14:01.247Z'
    },{
        name:'updated',
        type:'datetime',
        value: '2021-03-27T23:14:01.247Z'
    },{
        name:'active',
        type:'bit',
        value: true
    }]);
```

Comment: Unless you have good reason to let the application set these, you could always setup the columns to use default values e.g. `DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()`